# Accessing local version of library when system version is installed

Tags: python, python-3.x, linux, file, pytest

I want to test an edited version of a library, so I put it in my local directory. However, when I try to access the local library it shows the older version that's installed on my system.

I have already tried inserting the library to to the system path using
`sys.path.insert(0, '/home/abs/path/to/edited_lib')` but it still defaults to the system version of the library when I import it.

Answer (score 0):

To use a different version of a system library, you should use [Python's virtual environments](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/venv.html).

Go into your main project and create the virtual environment:

```
>>>  python -m venv ./your_env
```

Then activate it:

```
>>>  source ./your_env/bin/activate
```

Once inside (indicated by the environment name in brackets in the console) you should install your regular dependencies as usual. For example:

```
(your_env) >>>  pip install fastapi
```

To install your local version of a library do this:

```
(your_env) >>>  pip install -e /home/abs/path/to/edited_lib
```

This is called the editable mode install. Read more about it [here](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/topics/local-project-installs/#editable-installs).

**Make sure that you execute your python code from within the virtual environment so the local library dependencies are used.**